# What is the quickest route to Nioloko-Koba National Park(Senegal) from Gambia?

Tags: transportation, routes, africa, senegal

I've been reading many trip reports that cover The Gambia and Senegal in a single trip, but very few go into detail on which routes they are taking.

We will only have 2 weeks and want to focus on The Gambia, but also include a 2-3 day visit to Nioloko-Koba National Park to the east of The Gambia in neighboring Senegal.

I've already made the assumption that reaching it by public transport is a no-go, and that we'll need a driver.

Trying to plan and consider what routes to take or how to schedule our transportation within 2 weeks **I am looking to get an answer to the most reliable, quickest route to drive from central The Gambia to the  Nioloko-Koba National Park (entrance).** Based on actual experience or real knowledge of the area.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached out to several local guides/independent tour operators. These were the routes they describe:

- Banjul or Farafenni -> Kaolack -> Tambacounda -> Nioloko-Koba
- GeorgeTown -> Basse Santa Su-> Sabi -> Velingara  -> Tambakounda -> Nioloko-Koba

The first was the most common proposal.

I've not been able to validate that the 2nd route contains a legal border crossing.